# How to install googlemaps module on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am using `Python3.7` runtime and installed `googlemaps` module into `lib` folder using the command

```
$ python -m pip --upgrade install -t lib/ googlemaps
```

It worked fine locally. I deployed my flask project into Google cloud, where I defined the vendor in `appengine_config.py` as following:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
# Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

But when the project is deployed on google engine, I get this error:

```
 import googlemaps  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlemaps'
```

Any help please?

Comment: Which runtime are you using, Python 2.7 or Python 3.7?

Comment: @DustinIngram 3.7

Comment: does your `lib` folder have a `__init__.py`

Comment: @Alex yes, I worked! could you please write it as asnwer to accpet it !!

Comment: done! although this solved your issue, I do recommended setting up your dependencies the way Dustin explained in his answer

Comment: Yes, this is not the recommended way to install dependencies in the 3.7 runtime. Exactly right for 2.7, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your `lib` folder have a `__init__.py`?

It needs one as `lib` folder is treated as a package

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

But if you can, you should use a requirements.txt like @Dustin recommended. I've been on the python2 environment for years and my `lib` folder has grown into an unwieldy mess.

Answer (score 2):

The Python 3.7 is an "idiomatic" Python runtime. Among other things, it means that you don't need to bundle your dependencies along with your application like you used to have to do for the 2.7 runtime.

Instead, you should specify a `requirements.txt` file with the package name in it, like:

```
googlemaps==3.0.2
```

And this dependency will get installed the next time you deploy your app. See "[Specifying Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies)" for more details.